# How to pass a model value to a new route in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, model, routes

I have a products page that shows a list of products, clicking on one goes to a product page with some more detailed info on it as well as a purchase button that will send the user to a checkout page where I want to get the price as well as the title of the item and the image perhaps. But I'm just not sure how I can achieve that.

My templates look like this...

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="product">
<div id="product">
    <img {{bindAttr src="img"}}/>
    <div class="details">
        <p class="title">{{title}}</p>
        <span class="price">${{price}}</span>
        <p class="desc">
            {{desc}}
        </p>
        {{#link-to 'checkout' product classNames="buy"}}Buy This Item{{/link-to}}
    </div>
</div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="checkout">
    <h1>Checkout Page</h1>
    <p>{{price}}</p>
</script>
```

And the products route code looks like this...

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.findAll('product');
    }
});
```

And my make shift model looks like this...

```
App.Product.FIXTURES = [
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Black Shirt Mens',
    img: 'img/black-shirt-mens.jpg',
    price: 36,
    desc: 'Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.',
    type: 'shirt'
},
{
    id: 2,
    title: 'Black Shirt Womens',
    img: 'img/black-shirt-womens.jpg',
    price: 24,
    desc: 'Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.',
    type: 'shirt'
},
{
    id: 3,
    title: 'You Are Not a Mistake Poster',
    img: 'img/mistake-poster.jpg',
    price: 28,
    desc: 'Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.',
    type: 'poster'
},
{
    id: 4,
    title: 'White Shirt Mens',
    img: 'img/white-shirt-mens.jpg',
    price: 42,
    desc: 'Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.',
    type: 'shirt'
},
];
```

If you need me router object for clarity here it is...

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('products');
    this.resource('shirts',{path: 'products/shirts'});
    this.resource('product', { path: 'products/:product_id' });
    this.resource('checkout');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1) Specify the `/product` route in your Router

```
this.resource('products', function() {
    this.resource('product');
});
```

2) Set up your `products.index` route like this:

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.findAll('product');
    }
});
```

3) Create a `products/index` template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="products/index">
    {{#each}}
        {{#link-to "product" this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

4) You'll need to set the model for the `checkout` route.

```
App.CheckoutRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.modelFor('product');
    }
});
```

Also note that `{{#link-to 'checkout' product classNames="buy"}}Buy This Item{{/link-to}}` in your `product` template won't work, since you don't have a property of that name on your `App.Product` model. You probably want to change it to `{{#link-to 'checkout' this classNames="buy"}}Buy This Item{{/link-to}}` to pass the current product model.

jsBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/texiqepu/3/edit

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I didn't make it a nested route because I don't want to render it inside of the products route, I want it rendered inside the application route replacing the products route, but following what you said above anyway I was able to get the product to render in the outlet inside of products below the listing of products but when I try to add the 'this' keyword to the checkout link-to like you said nothing on the page renders at all.

Comment: Do you mind putting together a quick jsBin for this so I can have a look? There's a template at emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: By the way you don't need to use the `products.index` route if you don't want to. You can do all of that in the `application` route. Alternatively you could put a `redirect` into the `index` route to redirect the user to `products.index`

Comment: I was able to get this to work, however if the user refreshes on the checkout route, the model disappears, and in order to get the code to work again the user has to visit a different route and refresh and then click an item and click the purchase button again. Is there a way to fix this? Something like setting up a new model to use that info and clearing it once the user clicks another one or makes a purchase?